# AttributeError: module 'ClassMolecule' has no attribute 'save_molecule'

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods, attributeerror

Trying to understand the concept of the classes in Python, I wrote a little program with a molude 'ClassMolecule' in which I can define the attribute of molecules and also a method to save the attributes of my molecules in a file.

However when I use my method to save the properties in a file, Python raises an error saying that my module as not the method I used, i.e., the title of my question, as I understand it.

ClassMolecule.py

```
class Molecule:
    """
    Docstring
    """

    def __init__(self, name, T_eb, T_f, m_W, v_m, coefA, coefB, coefC):
        self.name = name
        self.T_eb = T_eb
        ...

    def save_molecule(self):
        with open('molecules_properties.txt', 'a') as f:
            for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
                f.append('%s:%s\n' % (key, value))
```

In another file, in the same folder, I did:

```
import ClassMolecule as CM

    water = CM.Molecule('water', '373', '273', '18', '0.018', '8.07131', '1730.63', '233.426')
    CM.save_molecule(water)
```

And the python raises the Error as mention above. And I don't understand why, since I defined my method in my class.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to call the method `save_molecule` of an object `water` is:

```
water.save_molecule()
```

Comment: I feel ashamed now.